# Initialize pointer to nullptr

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, initialization

Is there a difference in C++11 between the following pointer initialization:

```
#include <pwd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    passwd *p1{};
    passwd *p2{nullptr};

    return 0;
}
```

If I understand correctly, `p1` is zero-initialized, and `p2` is direct-initialized from `nullptr`. Is it the same thing? Is it possible to use initialization, as in the case of `p1`, because it requires fewer keystrokes?

Comment: They're equivalent, and which to use is entirely opinion-based. You left out the most common initialization vernacular: `passwd *p3 = nullptr;`, which is arguably the most clear in function *and* intent, regardless of how many precious keystrokes, and the extre half-second it takes to tap them, you're saving.

Comment: "*`p1` is zero-initialized*" - technically, it is [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), but since `p1` is a pointer type then the resulting value is [zero-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).